# Resize Image inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio

I know this question has been asked before, but the solutions out there did not work for me.

[image]

This is my image with max-width and max-height set to 100%.

Even when I set my max-width and max-height to 50% my image still does not aspect correctly. It is off centered.

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
 .container-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #e3f0da 
}

.container-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* x-axis */
  align-items: center;
  /* y-axis */
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background: #f2f2e2
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

img { 
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container-header">
        <div class="container-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display your `a` element as `block` and then you can center it using `test-align`.

```
li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.container-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #e3f0da 
}

.container-nav {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* x-axis */
  align-items: center;
  /* y-axis */
  font-size: 1.8em;
  background: #f2f2e2
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

img { 
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-header">
        <div class="container-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not telling it be centered in the a tag.

```
a{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kvp1a530/6/